# how to access an element with this shape with CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

My question is how can I select this element in CSS by `edit` ?

element :

```
<a href="***" class="example1 example2 example3" edit>click</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#attribute-selectors) by adding square brackets `[]`.

Attribute selectors can target:

- The name of the attribute: `a[edit]`
- The value of the attribute if it has one: `a[href=***]`

But since 'edit' is not a valid attribute for an `<a>`-Element, it's advisable to add an [data-](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) prefix in the html-code.

```css
a[data-edit]{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="***" data-edit>edit</a>
```

Comment: Is 'edit' a valid attribute for an <a> element? Didn't find it in the docs... so it might be advisable to add data-?

Comment: How to add data because yes your right. edit is not a valid attribute so I tried this and it did not work. However this is a good answer and I voted up.

Comment: `<a data-edit></a>` and `a[data-edit] {  }`.

Comment: Can I access it by example1.[data-edit]?

Comment: you'd use `.class[data-edit]`